# Uniform Convergence of Cauchy Sequence of Continuous Functions

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, analysis, topological-vector-spaces, complete-spaces

The definition of Cauchy Sequences in topological spaces is the following:

> Let $\{x_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ denote a Cauchy sequence. For any neighborhood $N$ of $0$, there exists a natural number $N$ such that $m, n \geq N$ gives $x_m - x_n \in N$.

Let $X$ denote a locally compact space. Consider $C(X, \mathbb{R})$ with the compact-open topology. Suppose that $N \subset C(X, \mathbb{R})$ is a compact neighborhood of $0$. Given a Cauchy sequence of continuous functions $\{f_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \subset C(X, \mathbb{R})$, does it follow that $\{f_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ converges uniformly to the function $f(x) = \lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(x)$?

The function $f$ is well-defined due the fact that $\{f_n(x)\}$ is Cauchy for each $x \in X$. However, I do not know how to proceed from here. I suspect that there is a relation between my doubt and the following result (taken from [Uniformly Cauchy Sequence article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniformly_Cauchy_sequence)), but I was unable to locate a proof.

> Let S be a topological space and M a complete metric space. Then any uniformly Cauchy sequence of continuous functions $f_n: S \to M$ tends uniformly to a unique continuous function $f: S \to M$.

Comment: What is $X$? A compact space?

Comment: $X$ is a locally compact space. I will update momentarily.

Comment: You do know that in general in $C(X,\Bbb R)$ $0$ does not have a compact neighbourhood? So the $N$ in the question does not exist at all. It only does for $X$ a finite space.

Comment: The statement for the uniformly Cauchy sequences is not for the compact-open topology but for the sup-norm topology, very different in  general.

Comment: Your definition of Cauchy sequence for general topological spaces does not make sense: $x_m-x_n$ requires subtraction of two elements, which does not even exist in general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $N \subseteq C(X,\Bbb R)$ is a compact neighbourhood of $0$ it follows by standard results that $C(X,\Bbb R)$ is finite-dimensional and $X$ is a finite space and $C(X,\Bbb R) \simeq $\Bbb R^k$ for some $k \in \Bbb N$.

In that case $f_n \to f$ uniformly is trivial.

The final statement of uniformly Cauchy sequences holds for $C(X,\Bbb R)$ in the uniform metric, *not* for the compact-open topology in general.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\epsilon>0$. Then there exists $N>0$ such that for all $m,n\ge N$ and all $x\in X$ we have $|f_n(x)-f_m(x)|<\epsilon$. By letting $m\to\infty$, from this it follows that $|f_n(x)-f(x)|<\epsilon$ for all $n\ge N$ and all $x\in X$. Hence, $f_n\to f$ uniformly.